# Post request in Postman - Content Length Issue

Tags: postman

Using Postman Version 6.4.4 (6.4.4), on MAC, i am not able to run any of the post request which was working for previous releases.

I keep getting the following similar exception from my middleware. THe issue is not with my middleware as the same request are working when invoked from my app.

> The value 146 in the Content-Length request header is > than the
>   actual number of bytes in request body. Resend the request with the
>   correct content length

I tried to add 'Content-Length' to the header with some values < what is returned in the exception, in which case the request goes through but the request body is always empty.

Comment: There is already a new version (6.5.3). Have you tried to update your Postman to see if that has been solved? Maybe is a known bug and they have fixed it

Comment: updated to the latest release but still the issue exist